# PHP mailer can not send e-mail via SMTP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I made a PHP mailer but it's not working anymore. It used to work but i changed nothing. It doesnt send the email. I filled in all the neccesary information for it to work but it doesnt. I know im not quite clear with my problem that because i dont know what the problem is and im not really good if it comes to PHP.
Here's the code.

**This is the INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'helpers/security.php';

$errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
$fields = isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Contact form</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="contact">

    <?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php  endif; ?>
    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
        <label>
            Your name*
            <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" <?php echo     isset($fields['name']) ? 'Value="' . e($fields['name']) . '"' : '' ?>>
        </label>
        <label>
            Your email address *
            <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" <?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? 'Value="' . e($fields['email']) . '"' : '' ?>>
        </label>
        <label>
            Your message *
            <textarea name="message" rows="8"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?></textarea>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Send">

        <p class="muted">* Means a required field</p>
    </form>
</div>



</body>
</html>

<?php
unset($_SESSION['errors']);
unset($_SESSION['fields']);
?>
```

**This is the CONTACT.PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once "libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

$errors = [];


if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])) {

$fields = [
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    "message" => $_POST['message']
];

foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
    if(empty($data)){
        $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
    }
}

    // 587 is voor uitgaande email deze is SSL en SMTP.ziggo.nl
    // 993 is voor inkomende email deze is TLS en IMAP.ziggo.nl
    // 110 is voor inkomende email deze is POP3 en
if(empty($errors)){

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com';
    $mail->Username = 'example';
    $mail->Password = 'secret';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 69;

    $mail->isHTML();

    $mail->Subject = 'Contact form submitted';
    $mail->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' ('. $fields['email'] .') <p>'. $fields['message'] .'</p>';

    $mail->FromName = 'Contact';

    $mail->AddAddress('email', 'name');

    if($mail->send()){
        header('Location: bedankt.php');
        die();
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry we konden de email niet verzenden, Probeer later  nog een keer.';
    }
}

} else {
$errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

header('location: index.php');
```

I hope you guys can help me with the information i've given here.
If something is missing please say so

**UPDATE**
The problem has been solved. I had nothing to do with the code but it was an isseu with the host, Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add this to your code `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;` and have a look at the output

Comment: Unfortunatly thats doesnt solve it :(

Comment: What makes you certain that your statement "It doesnt send the email." actually is true?

Comment: It wasn't meant to solve it, it should provide an error output that will describe the error you are having, if any.

Comment: Because i didnt recieve the email.

Comment: That does not mean it has not been sent. There are things like SPAM protection.

Comment: Does the header indeed go to bedankt.php? If it does, then the mailer did its job. Make sure you add exit; after each header also.

Comment: It doesnt sent it to bedankt.php it just shows the message that it didnt work and it didnt send

Comment: You may have syntax errors so use error reporting.

Comment: What do you mean Fred? I'm new to this kind of stuff so can u maybe explain?

Comment: Someone left you an answer below.

Comment: I know but that doesnt work. i tried already

Comment: You need to post a comment under the answer and let them it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rainier you want to use the ziggo smtp? also you can use this: `$mail->ErrorInfo;` to see error info

Comment: No i want to use custom email adress form a company. its like this Rainierguy@customurl.com. (ofcource thats not the email but thats an example)

Comment: There must be something wrong with the smtp settings, can you provide the e-mail hoster name so we can check the smtp settings? Also did you try my error option?

Comment: I tried the error option and i didnt do anything. And with email hoster name what do you mean? just the email

Comment: @Rainier something like Gmail, Zoho, Hotmail, your webhoster name

Comment: We use @birsken Its custom i think because its the company name im working for

Comment: This is the only error that shows, http://prntscr.com/cw7pvk

Comment: @Rainier that is an javascript warning. I have checked your e-mail provider, this is a small company that does not have there smtp settings online available. Can you change your else option to the following: `echo $mail->ErrorInfo; exit;` also add `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` Now you should see a error.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\oefeningen\contact form\contact.php on line 28

Comment: Sorry i mean, this is the error http://prntscr.com/cw7x07

Comment: That error is explained in the troubleshooting guide the error links to; you have a DNS or network problem, not a code problem. Please read what is right in front of you. Also don't post screen shots of text errors, it's a waste of time; just post the text, ideally in your question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First: In contact.php are you sure about port 69 and why not 587 ?
if you are using ziggo the $mail->Host  must be smtp.ziggo.nl
Uitgaande serverinstellingen
server: smtp.ziggo.nl
serverpoort: 587
 Use ssl:  type versleuteling: STARTTLS, TLS of SSL
Be carefull with $mail->isSMTP(); that it is true $mail->isSMTP(true);

```
working example:
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require $path.'/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; //the downloaded zip with PHPMailerAutoload i have put into a directoru called phpmailer!!
//require 'PHPmailer.php';

$_error = '';

 // insert configs
 $_smtpAuth = 'true';  //true
 $_smtpSecure = 'SSL';   // TLS og SSL
 $_smtpHost = 'send.one.com';  //one.com has send.one.com //gmail has smtp.gmail.com
 $_smtpPort = '465';
 $_smtpUsername = 'xxx@qwerty.com'; //your email address or username
 $_smtpPassword = 'xxxXxxxy';   //your password

 $mail = new PHPmailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP(true);                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = $_smtpHost;//$_smtpHost.';smtp2.example.com';       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = $_smtpAuth;                         // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $_smtpUsername;                     // SMTP username
$mail->Password = $_smtpPassword;                     // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = $_smtpPort;                             // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('name@yourwebmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('', '');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('', ''); //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('name@awebmail.com');  //Recipient  The sender of the email
$mail->addBCC('');

$mail->addAttachment('');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
                    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
                    require("class.phpmailer.php");

                    $mail = new phpmailer();
                    $mail->IsSMTP();                                   // per SMTP verschicken
                    $mail->Host     = "example.com"; // SMTP-Server
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // SMTP mit Authentifizierung benutzen
                    $mail->Username = "example";  // SMTP-Benutzername
                    $mail->Password = "example"; // SMTP-Passwort

                    $mail->From     = "test@example.com";//any address
                    $mail->FromName = "example";
                    $mail->AddAddress($to,"");
                    $mail->IsHTML(true);                               // als HTML-E-Mail senden
                    $mail->Subject  =  "Confirmation mail ";
                    $mail->Body     =  "<html><body>Dear example <br/><br/><br/>  \nKind regards\n<br/><br/> KM </body></html>";

                    if(!$mail->Send())
                    {
                        echo "error";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "send";
                    }
```

Comment: sometime senders server have firewall. If requester ip is not added then its denied email validation and sending mail fails.

Comment: Don't post unexplained code, especially when it's entirely different to the OP's and doesn't answer the question. You're using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an obsolete example. Not helpful.

Comment: hi, i don't know why its not working for you. difference is  $mail->IsHTML(true);  .  i am using same code and i can receive mail.@Rainier

Comment: same class of PHPMailer is used. so i send a code. next time i will take care of same output code. thanks @Synchro

Comment: It helps to read the question (though it's not very clear) - the problem is nothing to do with the code.